# ServiceStack4 JoinSqlBuilder issue when combining sqlite and postgresql

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Im having an issue with a project where I'm including both servicestack.ormlite.sqllite32 and servicestack.ormlite.postgresql.

When using the JoinSqlBuilder, it produces varying SQL based on which nuget packages are installed in my solution.

Using this code:

```
var builder = new JoinSqlBuilder<Entities.ServiceInstance, Entities.ServiceInstance>();

builder
    .LeftJoin<Entities.ServiceInstance, TokenServicesInstance>(x => x.Id,
        x => x.ServiceInstanceId)
    .Join<TokenServicesInstance, Token>(x => x.TokenId, x => x.Id,
                destinationWhere: t => t.TokenString == masterTokenString);
```

When calling builder.ToSql(), I will, going against the same database, get a postgresql version in one project:

> SELECT "service_instance"."id","service_instance"."service_name" 
>   FROM "service_instance" 
>    LEFT OUTER JOIN  "token_services_instance" ON "service_instance"."id" = "token_services_instance"."service_instance_id"
>    INNER JOIN  "token" ON "token_services_instance"."token_id" = "token"."id"
>   WHERE ("token"."token_string" = 'D0441CBF-AC8E-4664-974D-A2F325408AD2')

and a sqllite version in another project:

> SELECT "ServiceInstance"."Id","ServiceInstance"."ServiceName" 
>   FROM "ServiceInstance" 
>    LEFT OUTER JOIN  "TokenServicesInstance" ON "ServiceInstance"."Id" = "TokenServicesInstance"."ServiceInstanceId"
>    INNER JOIN  "Token" ON "TokenServicesInstance"."TokenId" = "Token"."Id"
>   WHERE ("Token"."TokenString" = 'D0441CBF-AC8E-4664-974D-A2F325408AD2')

Looking at the code here:
[JoinSqlBuilder ServiceStack3 source](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/JoinSqlBuilder.cs) I'm not that surprised, assuming the code hasn't changed much to version 4.

There is a reference to a static OrmLiteConfig with a property DialectProvider.
Debugging my projects this property changes between them. One is *ServiceStack.OrmLite.PostgreSQL.PostgreSQLDialectProvider* the other is *ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider*.

And yes, clearly I'm not passing any info into the joinsql telling it which dialect to use, so maybe I should have seen this one coming.

So my questions are

- Can I reference more than one OrmLite-implementation in the same project, expecting it to be stable? Is the JoinSqlBuilder the only problem?
- Is there a workaround so that I can use the JoinSqlBuilder in my project?
- Why? Why is ServiceStack architectured with such use of statics? There is quite heavy use of extension functions already, making it harder to write tests.. Should I expect more surprises?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found this question and answer on google: [What's the reasoning behind providing OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider as a singleton?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/servicestack/2xdYG5uJ_pg/kAOMsg281jIJ)

Quoting mythz:

> OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider is a Singleton because everything in OrmLite is an extension method (over the core ADO.NET Interfaces), so it needs to be static.

And:

> OrmLite doesn't really support multiple different db providers used at the same time.

After what I've seen, it doesn't really come as a surprise. I guess I have to move one of the databases, which handles cross-cutting authorization, into it's own service.

Comment: I just ran into a similar issue but found the issue is the custom naming convention used by the PostgreSQL provider. Some contributor, almost a year ago, decided he preferred column names with underscores in them. So if your object has member TokenService.ServiceName, the postgresql driver will generate token_service.service_name. I ran into this when cutting over from an MSSQL database with a column named "alertLevel" to PostgreSQL, and the same code was looking for "alert_level" - and thus breaking.  PostgreSQL appears to be the only provider that does this.